# Where is an enum stored?

Tags: c, assembly, enums, compilation

I was surprised when doing the following that no assembly is produced for the `Enums`:

[image]

I thought perhaps it would do something like:

```
Hello:
    .byte 0
Goodbye:
    .byte 1
```

It seems it only adds in the values when assigned to a var:

[image]

Why is this so? Why don't the 'enum values' get stored when declared (even if I set `Hello=1`)? Example link: https://godbolt.org/z/xxnMvq.

Comment: They are stored in the compiler's data set so they can be used in other places in the program.`enum { Hello, Goodbye }` defines values, not a variable. Then, the `1` was used at label `c:`

Comment: They're not stored; they are constants available at compiler level and simply translated to integers whenever they are used in statements.

Comment: Related: [where and how are the values in each of the members of enum stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45845557/where-and-how-are-the-values-in-each-of-the-members-of-enum-stored-in-c), also [Why does the size of enum only correspond to the size of a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65485445/why-does-the-size-of-enum-only-correspond-to-the-size-of-a-single-value).

Comment: If you had done `enum {Hi, Bye} greeting;` then `greeting` would be a variable of type enum.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An enum is not a variable, it is a type. The different enum labels are in fact constants.
Being a type it requires no space in your final binary.

The compiler internally keeps a list of them and replaces every use of them with the constant they represent.

These values do however end up in the debugging info, if it is generated, so you can use them in your debugger.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you. Also surprised to see that it wasn't in the original K&R C either.